# Dynamic Form with Upload

Tags: php, html, laravel

Straight to the point.

I have dynamic field form. Per row, I need to insert multiple file attachments.

For example i have 3 field row.

Row 1 = 3 files

Row 2 = 2 Files

Row 3 = 3 Files

When I dd($request->all()) the files (upload[]) are not group per row, it became 8, how do i group the files?

Thanks.

[image: Form]

[image: Output]

Form Code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="date[]" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="category[]">
            <option selected disabled value="">Please Select</option>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control numeric" name="cost[]" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, you form have button to add row?

Comment: @sokhai yes, it have add button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add new class to you input like this:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="upload[]" class="uploads" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
```

then i create function changeUploadName() and call it when you click on add new or delete row.

```
function changeUploadName() {
    $(".uploads").each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr('name', 'upload' + index + '[]');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `name` attribute to an unique name.

To capture the request at in the laravel controller, I come out with unique variable to capture the variable.

Example:

Blade View

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="upload_{{ $id }}[]" class="uploads" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$store->file = $request->{'upload_'.$id}
```